# Partition on Flash drive to have ubuntu + files

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

I have Windows 10 installed and it currently occupies all of my disk. I want to make a new partition to install Debian Linux. The problem is that i already have 4 disks on my windows: One for system recovery, one is reserved for the system, the other is a Local disk C: and the other is another Local disk (D:).

Original question, no need to answer:

> Since i can't create a new partition without it being a dynamic disk, is there a way to install Debian Linux on my computer, without having to merge together C: and D:? (I don't wanna do that because it would take like forever to copy all the files from D to C).

**EDIT:**

As stated by Ramhound in his comment, it is not possible to do what i want. So i have another option.
I have a 64GB Flash drive that is empty. I want to install debian (or ubuntu) on it, but i want to use like 50GB or so of the flash drive, not all of it. How can i do that? is it possible?

Comment: You would have to delete a partition, and convert your disk to GPT, to accomplish what you want

Comment: Another option i see is installing ubuntu on a Pen-Drive. Can i create two partitions in my pen drive, and install ubuntu in one of them, leaving the other for some files? The pen drive is currently empty, but i might wanna use it for storing data in the future.

Comment: convert your local D: to logical disk and create another logical disk. That's the simplest way

Answer (score -1):

Backup all the files from D. You don't need to merge together C: and D: drives. You don't need to convert to dynamic disk either. Dynamic disk is created when you are going to use RAID like features such as create volumes that span multiple disks. Basic disk with primary and logical partitions work for you. After taking backup, simply delete the partition D: and you will get unallocated space. Then create extended partition with all necessary logical partitions require for windows files and for Debian Linux. 
You can also partition your flash drive to use 50GB from 64GB for linux and rest for copying files. When you connect this USB on PC you can't see the 50GB in windows. But you can boot from it by choosing options from BIOS